# Ubuntu hosting VPN for personal VPN network

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dns, vpn

This is probably a simple solution and I am missing something but I have a home network that does not have a static IP and I have a domain controller and a samba share on that DC, I want to be able to host a VPN on my cloud ubuntu server that does have a static IP and I want to be able to have the DC set as a static IP in the VPN network (like 22.22.22.100) and I want to have the names resolved anywhere inside the VPN, I also want to be able to have a laptop that can login to the Domain from a laptop that is on the VPN. I also need to be able to access the fileserver from my Mac and iPhone.

Summary:

- VPN server hosted on Ubuntu Server
- VPN sets the exampleserver as the primary DNS for the VPN so that names will resolve
- VPN allows other computers to login to the Domain even if not on internal network.

What could I do for this?

Comment: Read the Digital Ocean tutorial on setting up an OpenVPN server on Ubuntu.

Comment: @OrganicMarble that doesn’t include the Static IP configuration.

Comment: Best wishes on setting up your system!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.